# How To Read Values Within Arrays In Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, immutable.js

Im a bit confused about this and cant seem to work this out.

Say I have this:

```
const AnObj = Immutable.Map({
 a : "a",
 b : Immutable.List.of(
  a,
  b,
  c,
  Immutable.Map({
   a : "a"
  })
 )
});
```

With Immutable Maps, we use strings within `get()` to find the corresponding properties. How do we read array values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer - This applies to all Immutable types, not just List.

Several ways -

1. The [`get`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/get) method -
   `AnObj.get('b').get(3).get('a')` (Thanks @stas).
   This is useful when the structure is not very deep. As you see, the syntax is very verbose.
2. The succinct [`getIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/getIn) -
   `AnObj.getIn(['b', 3, 'a'])`
   I love this because this pattern allows having a generic getter and I can toss the key-path around to the various components.
3. The veritable [valueSeq](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/valueSeq)/[entrySeq](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/entrySeq), when you want all the values and don't care for indices -
   `AnObj.get('b').valueSeq()`
   This is useful when the list is huge and you want to delay the iteration until its absolutely needed. This is the most performant of them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass numeric zero-based indexes to `List.get()`:

```
AnObj.get('b').get(3).get('a')
```

See https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/get.